# Some way to count elements in a property in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

Hi I have a node that represents an email, and one of the properties is the recipients (e.g. { 'john@doe.com', 'max@example.com' }.
Is there a way that I can count how many recipients each email has?

Comment: what is the type of your "recipient" property? is it a `List` or are you using multiproperties or something else?

Comment: @stephenmallette it is a JSON

Answer (score 3):

So assuming:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('emails','["x@x.com","y@y.com"]')
==>v[0]
```

I'd start by saying that you should probably parse that JSON to multi-properties if your graph supports it because then you get a more natural approach to dealing with that data. It would be something like:

```
g.V(0L).values('emails').count()
```

Gremlin simply doesn't have native methods for parsing JSON so that leaves you with two options I guess:

1. Use a lambda and a Groovy `JsonSlurper`
2. Just return the JSON string and parse it on the client to get your count in your native programming language.

If you were using a lambda it would look like this:

```
gremlin> json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
==>groovy.json.JsonSlurper@421a4ee1
gremlin> g.V(0L).values('emails').map{json.parseText(it.get())}
==>[x@x.com,y@y.com]
gremlin> g.V(0L).values('emails').map{json.parseText(it.get())}.count(local)
==>2
```

Note that this assumes your graph supports lambdas and that you can make use of `JsonSlurper` in that environment. We typically try to get folks to avoid lambdas so your best choice would be to model your data better (i.e. multiproperties or a `List`) or to process the JSON locally.